# How to build bread crumb style text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm building an order for a pizza. I would like to have the text displayed under the sections to show the order so far. IE,

Hand-Tossed Crust, 14", Extra Cheese, Anchovies

But each piece be a clickable link that would take the back to that section to modify their order. For instance, if they click 14", it will take them back to select pizza size. If they click Hand-Tossed Crust, take them back to select crust. It looks like this...

[image]

Android's TextView is clickable. I can add links, I know, but how can I add the link so that it jumps to a different section of the app (maybe fire an intent).

In the interim, tapping the text view takes you back to the last thing, but I'd rather have it work like bread crumbs.

Comment: What do you mean with "different section of the app"? Is this section a fragment, an activity, something else? I think there is a lack of information if you want an answer specific to your question.

Comment: Hi, you could share an image of what your needs, it will explain that more clearly.

Comment: @Cheesebaron, The order process is a single activity. There are various screens like "choose a crust." That's what I mean by different parts of the app.

Comment: You don't mention _how_ you show these, are they just views that you scroll to or how does it actually work?